# log4net not working

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, log4net

Hey I have this configuration in my web.config

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="mylog.log" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="Header" value="" />
            <param name="Footer" value="" />
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="Header" value="[Header]\r\n" />
            <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]\r\n" />
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

but log4net is not working. My project compiles fine, and I get no errors debugging either. The lines where I tell to `log.debug("somemessage")` gets run fine, but I can't find the `mylog.log` file, so where is it?

Comment: Be sure to check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24617269/114029

Answer (score 315, accepted):

One gotcha for this type of thing is to make sure to add the `XmlConfigurator` attribute to the assembly by placing the following line in your `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator]
```

Otherwise log4net never activates.

Comment: This method **used** to work in my project, but it stopped working somehow. I had to use this method http://stackoverflow.com/a/1479343/193634 to make it work again.

Comment: I just tried it again and it works fine.  Most likely you are not referencing/loading the assembly that contains the `AssemblyInfo` as soon as you thought.

Comment: For those using ELMAH appender this is the way to go. I had 'log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();' in global.asax.cs and it was working fine for file appender but not for ELMAH appenders.

Comment: I've up-ticked this answer and found I needed to tweak it with ` [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)] `

Comment: or [assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")], if log4net configured in separate file, '/log4net.config', as in my case

Answer (score 51):

I guess that either log4net is not logging at all, or the file is not ending up where you expect it.

Firstly, have you actually called

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure()
```

anywhere in your code? If the xml snippet above is in the application configuration file, this call will do the trick. If the xml snippet is in it's own file, you'll need to use the `.Configure(string)` overload that takes the path to the file. Without this call (or apparently the assembly level attribute mentioned by Kirk Woll), then log4net won't be logging at all.

If you believe this is all done, and log4net should be logging, then maybe you should put a fully qualified path in for the log file while you debug further. That will let you be sure where the file *should* be.

Answer (score 35):

There is another small gotcha, see here: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#dot-config

the `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator]` method doesn't work with app.config. If you configure log4net from app.config, you must use the `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()` method.

Comment: Just for the record, both methods worked for me in an console application.

Comment: I confirm the solution above - I had to invoke  log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); in my code (which uses app.config  to have log4net effectively work.  Lines which get effectively printed are those subsequent to the execution of Configure() method.

Answer (score 23):

Here is my checklist for when log4net is proving to be recalcitrant:

- ensure that log4net.config file is copied to the bin\ folder when building (set to 'Copy if newer' in compiler)

  - when dealing with installed code, ensure that the log4net.config came along for the ride (set to 'Content' in compiler)
- ensure that the user that the process runs as has write rights to the folder where the logs are to be written
- if in doubt, give promiscuous permissions to c:\temp\ and get everything to log to there ()
- fire up Sysinternal/Dbgview.exe to see if that tells you anything

Comment: "ensure that log4net.config file is copied to the bin\ folder when building (set to 'Copy if newer' in compiler)"
-> save my day! Thks so much!

Answer (score 9):

For an ASP.NET MVC project adding

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

to the Global.asax.cs also helps:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
}
```

Comment: Had a very weird issue with this, in production and on my boss's computer the loggers worked fine like this, but not until I Kirk's answer did it work on my computer. Just thought I'd let people know in case they have similar issues (MVC project btw).

Comment: @Shelby115, many many thanks! I was trying to put my log4Net entries in ELMAH. I had everything correct in web.config. I already had 'log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();' in my global.asax.cs but it wan't working. Came to this SO post and added the line to assemblyInfo.cs  based on Kirk's. It still didn't work!. After reading your comment I deleted the previous entry from global.asax.cs and it started working. I spent several hours on this and your comment was a big help. Thanks again!

Comment: The entry in global.asax.cs was working fine for file appender but not for ELMAH appenders. Kirk's way worked for ELMAH appender (I specifically had to remove it form global.asax.cs)

Comment: You might also want to ensure that log4net has write permissions to the directory configured for the log files.

Comment: @Shelby115 Dang, gotta love it when you forget the solution and your own comment solves your problem. Coming to a page with an answer already upvoted by you is a good indicator too.

Answer (score 7):

These are the steps which eventually got my file logging working:

- -Check AssemblyInfo.cs contains the following attribute. 
     **[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator]**. This loads log4net.
- Check the log directory has write permissions.
- Check the logger has a format specified. This is done by checking each  element in your configuration has a **layout** element specified. Eg:

`<appender name="MainLogger"...
       <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout"/>`

- Finally, try turning on log4net internal logging to enable console logging and checking the console. To do this, add `<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>` to your `appSettings`.

Comment: <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/> This helped me to troubleshoot the issue. Thanks

Comment: The directory's permissions is what got me

Answer (score 6):

I've had experiences where logging systems fail silently without raising exceptions.  I suppose this makes sense because if the logger is logging errors then how can it log an error that it's unable to perform logging?

So if the file isn't created on disk, start by **looking into file system permissions** to ensure the user your application is running under can write a new file to that disk location.

For testing purposes you might want to manually create the file on disk that should be written to and open up permissions for everybody to write to it.  If the logger starts writing to it then you know it's permission based rather than configuration based.

Answer (score 4):

On my side, I forgot to mark the config file to be copied while the app is being compiled.

[image: Copy the config file to output directory]

Just right click the log4net.config file, select property and then choose Copy to Output Directory to be Copy XXXX

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately none of the above helped. Explicit configuration in the class to be logged additionaly to the previous settings suggestions did the trick for me.

```
string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(assemblyFolder + "/log4net.config"));
```

Comment: Thanks none of the above worked but yours. You are my hero!

Answer (score 2):

So, in the Accepted Answer, the solution was to put

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator]
```

into the `AssemblyInfo.cs` File.

Also, there was a comment sugesting

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

however, if it is still not working, consider configuring the name of your log4net config file (`log4net.config` in my case):

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]
```

after that, logging worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above but nothing worked. Adding this line in **app.config's** `configSections` section worked for me.

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" />
```

Ensure that `Version` and `PublicKeyToken` is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
<param name="File" value="mylog.log" />
```

is saying "write mylog.log to actual folder". This means that if your webapp is under IIS, then log will be written to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\appname\mylog.log.

If log file is not there, then maybe account under which is app running doesn't have write permission on folder. You can run Process Monitor from SysInternals to see if and where a file is written.

Also run VS in debug mode, to see if any exceptions are thrown (Debug->Exceptions->CLR Exceptions, check Thrown).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forget to set the log4Net.config file properties as "Content" so the file was not included in the deploy.
So pay attention on it:

```
Compile action : Content
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Reporting level is set to "Debug" or "ALL".
This caught me and I spent ages trying to debug my log4net setup.
I had it set to Error and as it wasn't erroring it didn't log anything.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from all the other answers, my problem that was I needed a call to GetLogger() in my start-up class (WinForms example):

```
static class Program
{
    public static readonly ILog MainLog = LogManager.GetLogger("Main");

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

All my 'meaningful' logging statements were in a DLL that is apparently loaded too late for log4net.

Answer (score 0):

We also had problems with log4net not working and in our case the problem was  that the config file had Windows line breaks instead of Unix line breaks.

Answer (score -7):

Also after some hours, I figured out why it wasn't working for me...

i had:

```
public static class Program
{

    private static CommunicationManager _bcScanner = new CommunicationManager();
    private static ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
    private static SocketServer socketListener;
```

but it should be:

```
public static class Program
    {
        private static ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
        private static CommunicationManager _bcScanner = new CommunicationManager();
        private static SocketServer socketListener;
```

So make sure the ILog is on the first line....

Comment: This is definitely not the cause. It doesn't matter when you  initialize the ILog object as long as you do that before you make a call to the logging methods i.e _log.Info; _log.error etc.