# log4net is not creating log file to log

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

log4net is not creating any text file to log. I tried like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="EpinovaADSyncJob.log" />
  <appendToFile value="false" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
</configuration>
```

In assembly file:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(
ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

Declared as class variable

```
 private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(
 MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

In a method, called the Log like this

```
BasicConfigurator.Configure();
        Log.Debug("Myjob");
        Log.Error("newlkjasdf");
        Log.Info("lkjlkjasdfasdf");
```

Comment: I have not used the assembly reference. I always use log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); I do not believe that obviates the need for this initialization.

Comment: @JamieMeyer, no, [the assembly attribute is sufficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898218/log4net-not-working/3898254#3898254).

Comment: I tried this config and it did create a file, `***\bin\Debug\EpinovaADSyncJob2015-11-05.log`. Are you sure the config is being loaded and the relevant account has permissions to write the file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this appender :

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file value="log.txt" />
<appendToFile value="false" />
<rollingStyle value="Size" />
<maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
<maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n" />
</layout>
```