# How do I use log4net within a dll that does not depend on a client's app or web.config?

Tags: c#, logging, azure, log4net

I want to be able to dynamically control the level of logging my Azure cloud-based applications perform. To do this I'm creating a shared log4net-based DLL.

There are lots of questions about log4net logging but almost all of them involve entering and manipulating settings in a config file or other text file. In the Azure cloud, changing the web.config means redeploying. I want to change the logging by making web service calls into the applications from an admin portal.

I also have several applications and I want each to use my new log4net-based DLL without having to store identical settings such as Appender details in each config file. The applications log the same, consistent data.

I do not want to use the Azure diagnostics because this will reduce performance of this large user base application. In addition, I want to reduce logging and diagnostics to a minimum (or disable completely) and only enable them at various levels to debug production problems or take snapshots of their performance. I don't want to redeploy my apps.

What's the best approach?

Comment: Thanks to John M Gant for this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769983/how-to-configure-log4net-programmatically-from-scratch-no-config

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend not storing log4net configuration in web/app.config files but rather in a different file that can be updated externally (ie: in blob storage) and location of which can be dynamically changed from the Service Config or contents of which can be changed w/o redeploying.

Look into the log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure method.  You can pass it many different parameters instead of just calling it with no parameters (no parameters default method reads from app.config files).

One way to do what you want is to pass that Configure method a public URL of a config file stored in your Azure storage.  Location of the config file can be controlled from the Service Config.

Alternatively if you do not want to make the config file public, you can implement your own reader of the XML config from some private location in storage and pass the XML document to the Configure() method instead.

Check for more information here:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Comment: I was just going to say the same thing...LOL :)

Answer (score -1):

I can think of 2 ways:

Use Web Deploy which just updates the files on the server without having to do the full blown deployment process.

Enable RDP on your Azure instances and just log in and alter the config file in situ, just like any other server

Comment: This still requires the duplication of appender details within each application's web.config. I want to store the appender details in a location that's common to all applications.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood the question see this post on how to move the log4net config out of the web config and then you can just update all your web configs to point to this same file.  Then you have one file to change and it will affect all apps.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445976/log4net-config-in-external-file-does-not-work

Comment: I would not recommend any of the mentioned approaches. Simply because the changes done in either way will be lost upon Upgrade service, Role Recycle, Guest OS Update/Path, Hardware failure and consequent move of current instance to another hardware, and probably a few other reasons.

Comment: So are you essentially saying Web Deploy is useless?

Comment: yes. I would enable and use WebDeploy only on a Single Instanced WebRole and do it only during fine-tuning / debugging / testing stage. Definitely not use WebDeploy for Azure WebRole in production.