# Log4Net Retrieve Appenders Programmatically

Tags: c#-4.0, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender, slf4net

I have a separate `Log4Net.config` file with 2 appenders and 2 loggers, 1 logger for each appender. There is no `<Root />` logger.

I am trying to add code to my application that will retrieve the filename for the logger to allow the user to view the log files for each of the appenders from an application menu selection. I have tried the below code but it returns no appenders. What did I miss?

I should also have mentioned that I am using the slf4net.log4net facade

```
log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository repo = LogManager.GetRepository();

foreach (log4net.Appender.IAppender appender in repo.GetAppenders())
{
    string x = appender.Name;
}
```

Comment: Did you call `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` first? This works for me.

Comment: Calling XmlConfigurator.Configure() causes the logger to return an error, "Failed to find the configuration section log4net in the applications .config file. I should also have mentioned that I am using the slf4net.log4net facade. Adding the node to the config didn't help. It still returned the error.

Comment: Also note that I have [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)] in the AssemblyInfo.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in this post [log4Net config in external file does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445976/log4net-config-in-external-file-does-not-work/445988#445988). After adding the ConfigFile name to the assemblyinfo entry it began working